# iPhone - when testing on device

Tags: ios5

**Couldn't register com.companyname.myapplicationname with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code. This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.Program received signal: “SIGABRT”**

I tried removing the app from the simulator, doing a clean build but I still get this error when I try to run the app.
What should I do to be able to run the app on my simulator again?

Comment: ya i tried again i am getting same error

Comment: we are talking about your mac, not the simulator, right?

Comment: no,when i want run on device

Comment: yes, i tried reset content and settings still getting same  error

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your device, resetting your device if possible, restart Xcode, restart your Mac, clear the Xcode cache and project cache, make a project clean etc.

Some of this should help.